# Limiting imagery displayed to non-rectangular area using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, imagery, data-frame

I have a layer that shows some imagery in Ontario. I would like to get rid of the imagery that I don't need, because I only need it to be in 6 "squares" that I have.

[image]

Is there a way to restrict the imagery to this area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to clip for cartographic reasons and do not want to generate a clipped raster, you may do this via Data Frame Properties if your grid layer is a polygon. 
  Data Frame Properties>Data Frame>Clip Options>Specify Shape (use your grid layer here).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You want to clip your raster (image) by your feature layer (your six squares). [Simon Woo's article](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/10/05/clipping-imagery-and-raster-data-in-arcgis/) offers some solutions. If you have Spatial Analyst, [Extract by Mask](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extract_by_Mask/009z0000002n000000/) will do the trick.